# How to solve this linear system function (Using Laplace Transform)

Tags: improper-integrals, fourier-series, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace, laplace-method

Someone can help to solve this example?
[image]

Its really hard to find the solution step by step.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: The double pendulum is a nonlinear system. It cannot be handled directly by the Laplace transform without a previous linearization.

Comment: Ok. The system is

$I) (m1+m2)l1^2*theta1'' + m2*l1*l2*theta2'' + (m1+m2)l1*g*theta1 = 0
II)m2*l2^2*theta2'' + m2*l1*l2*theta1'' + m2*l2*g*theta2 = 0$